# Where to use which kind of font?

Tags: fonts

There are **Serif** fonts like *Times New Roman*, **Slab Serif** fonts like *Bree Serif*, **Sans Serif** fonts like Calibri, Arial, etc.

Times New Roman is well known but here is a sample of *Bree Serif*:

[image: Bree Serif]

My question is where to use these three different kinds of fonts? **Serif, Slab Serif, Sans Serif...**
Where are they best suitable for? **Headings, books, book covers, newspapers, magazines, brochures...**

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! I think there's potential in your question if it is not a duplicate but more based an overview on which type of support (paper/screen, etc). I would keep this open. No time to answer myself but maybe next week.

Comment: Hello. I am concerned on both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is all up to you what kind of font you use. Beside the [display fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_typeface) (that are designed to be used on headings) you can chose whatever font you need to create the desired [mood for you page](https://digitalsynopsis.com/design/font-psychology-emotions/) (even [Comic Sans](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enRO859RO859&source=univ&tbm=isch&q=best%20use%20of%20comic%20sans&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj8qN7_s9vqAhWlxIsKHWykC7MQsAR6BAgMEAE&biw=3411&bih=1047)).

For web design you should also take into consideration the performance of the page before you chose the mood of the page. If you load too many fonts (with many weights) the page will load too slow so you will have to optimize this by doing more with less. For example you could even use the fonts that are already available on the device of the user by using OS fonts or popular fonts like this:

`p{font-family:-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif}`

Answer (score 5):

There are **no rules**.

There is **no** "best used for X" regarding *any* typeface.

This is all what a **designer's aesthetic eye has to determine** for each piece designed and the **goal of that particular piece**. i.e for a lot of copy in print, a serif may work best... but if the goal is to promote a more "informational" atmosphere a serif typeface will be contrary to that.